# Angular checkboxes wont remain checked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have some angular.js code that populates an array when a user clicks on some checkboxes. I generate a list of checkboxes with an 'ng-repeat' and I need to save an array to the server side when a user submits a form. I have this code and it works.. [fiddle here..](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/4043/) However, the checkboxes wont stay 'checked'? does anyone have any advice on how to fix this UI bug?

html

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Search by Organism :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Organism" ng-model="filterText">
          </div>
          <div class="well" style="max-height: 250px; overflow: auto;">
              <ul class="list-group checked-list-box" ng-repeat="x in organisms | filter: filterText">
                  <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" ng-change="match($index)" ng-model="orgs[$index]"> {{ x }}
                  </label>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

angular

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.orgs = [];
        $scope.match = function(index) {
            console.log("index", index);
            console.log("organism: ", $scope.organisms[index]);
            $scope.orgs[index] = $scope.organisms[index];
        };

        $scope.organisms = ["Pseudomonas aeruginosa", "Stenotrophomonas maltophilia", "Pseudomonas luteola", "Pseudomonas aeruginosa", "Streptococcus pneumoniae", "Candida tropicalis", "IAV-H1N1", "IAV-H1N2", "IAV-H3N2", "IAV-mixed", "IAV-H10N8", "IAV-H2N2", "IAV-H5N1", "IAV-H5N6", "IAV-H7N3", "IAV-H7N7", "IAV-H7N9", "IAV-H9N2"];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out the line

```
$scope.orgs[index] = $scope.organisms[index]
```

This will prevent the array from being overwritten.

---

IMPROVEMENT

I have updated the fiddle. You can not click on the check boxes and save the values in another array. The best way to do this is to use the Array prototype `push`. Your new match function is below.

```
$scope.match = function(orgName) {
    var index= $scope.selection.indexOf(orgName);
    if (index> -1) {
        $scope.selection.splice(index, 1);
    }
    else {
        $scope.selection.push(orgName);
    }
};
```

Also, the check boxes have a property called value. This can be used as a placeholder for your data.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pparas/Lvc0u55v/4060/)

If that is what you wanted, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: How would I populate an array to save ? I need that line to populate the org's array for when the user submits a form..

Comment: also you fiddle is empty

Comment: I have updated my answer with a complete solution in a fiddle.

Comment: This is a great solution, exactly what I was looking for, Thanks! @pparas